# Compile time detection of functions

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, compile-time

I'm working on a little compile time helper that let's me determine if a function (for now: no namespaces or class member functions) with a specific signature exists (e.g. `__builtin_pop_count` which is widely spread, but not guaranteed to be available on any platform).

For a fixed number of arguments, this is easily done:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename ArgumentType, typename = void>
struct Exists : std::false_type // Base case
{
};

template <typename T>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T>
using return_t = decltype(foo(std::declval<T>())); // here it is hidden: foo, although this symbol is never declared!

// specialization (compiler has to pick this one if no substitution failure in return_t
template <typename ReturnType, typename ArgumentType>
struct Exists<ReturnType, ArgumentType, void_t<return_t<ArgumentType>>>
  : std::is_same<return_t<ArgumentType>, ReturnType> // check the return type
{
};

static_assert(!Exists<void, int>::value, "");
static_assert(!Exists<void, void>::value, "");
static_assert(!Exists<void, char*>::value, "");
static_assert(!Exists<int, void>::value, "");
static_assert(!Exists<int, int>::value, "");
static_assert(!Exists<int, char*>::value, "");
```

This compiles fine. Adding the function `void foo(int)` negates the first assertion, but leaves the rest intact.

Now I would like to extend this helper to support an arbitrary number of argument types.

However,

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes, typename = void>
```

cannot work, because `typename...` must be at the end of the list,

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename = void, typename... ArgumentTypes>
```

on the other hand requires the following ArgumentTypes to have a default type which also is not possible.

How can I circumvent this? Can a `std::tuple<ArgumentTypes...>` help in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You guessed it.
Use a `pack` template, and "simplify" a bit:

```
template <typename...> struct pack {}; // To be potentially introduced in C++1Z

template <typename, typename, typename=void>
struct Exists_impl : std::false_type {};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct Exists_impl<R, pack<Args...>,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(foo(std::declval<Args>()...)), R>::value>>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
using Exists = Exists_impl<R, pack<Args...>>;
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6b5fbe666024c58).
Note that this template will never be able to find functions like `void(int)` via ADL, as the set of associated namespaces is empty in such cases. Those functions must be declared at the point of definition.
Also it might be feasible to use `is_convertible` instead of `is_same` for the check of the return type, depending on the use-case.

Comment: When should one use `pack` over a regular tuple if they just want a type list?

Comment: @0x499602D2 A `tuple` is a heavy template. You should never use it in TMP unless really necessary.

Comment: If you use `is_convertible`, you probably want to specialize for `void` return type, unless you want `int foo();` to be incompatible with the signature `void()`.  Or not, if you prefer that to be blocked!